# How to see the entire history of my Ledger wallet?

Tags: ledger-hardware-wallet, xpub

I followed the instructions from [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/9aw4ut/how_to_get_public_key_from_ledger_live/) on how to find my xpub address and tapped the wrench icon button and then "Detailed logs" in Ledger Live.

The problem is that this xpub value works on neither [blockchain.com](https://blockchain.com) nor [blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com). The Ledger Live historical chart looks nice, but it only shows up to one year of historical balances.

How can I see my entire history of Bitcoin transactions made with the Ledger Nano S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use your Ledger via Electrum - it supports hardware wallets, will let you set the derivation path to match your address type, and has no limits on the history displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer here. Do you have any ideas about https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/how-to-retrieve-total-btc-held-in-ledger-wallet ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are different explorers that support xpub that will show history as well as balance

- [blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co)
- [blockpath](https://blockpath.com/wallets/new?action=appxpub)
- [smartbit](https://www.smartbit.com.au/)